# Background that scrolls down css

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how can I something like this with CSS & HTML:

https://www.vatsim.net

You open the page and you get a backrgound that fits all the browser, but then you scroll down and you get a solid color as background and more info.

I tried with this, but is not what I am looking for, I want something like the link on the top,

https://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand your question. The airplane 'background' is just a div, and even if it would be the page background, you could still have divs or other elements that have a solid color background that overlay the background image. The page you linked to uses JavaScript for this, by the way. I can tell by the changing 'style' attribute on aforementioned div.

Comment: @GolezTrol, could you give me a simple example of this? thank you very mcuh!

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get far by just adding a bit of CSS. In the snippet below, there are two divs. The first one is for the top area with the image. The second one is for the rest of the content.

The first div gets a height of 100vh, making it 100% of the screen height. The background image is centered and set to scale so it covers the entire div. And, well, that's basically all there is to it. No script needed.

```css
* { /* Just get rid of some whitespace */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.image {
  height: 100vh; /* div is 100% of viewport height */
  background-image: url(https://www.ancestry.com/wiki/images/archive/a/a9/20100708215937!Example.jpg);
  background-size: cover; /* Entire div is covered by the image */
  background-position: center; /* Image is centered relatively to the div. */
}

/* Just some styling to make it visible. */
div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
}

div.content {
  color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">This is the top area. The image exactly covers the view.</div>

<div class="content">This is the rest of the content. You can scroll down a bit just to see what happens.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The webpage you added is basicly splitted to divs, the first is 100% height and 100% width. therefore you can see him all over your screen.

The others are just divs with 100% width but not 100% height, which gives you the ability to switch the background color from light gray to white and then to gray.

Not too complicated but yet a nice design